# Is there a way to create a key binding that would allow me to mount my googledrive?

Tags: command-line, mount, keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-drive

I'm working on a CB3-532 Chromebook with GalliumOS and my google-drive-ocamlfuse is  working fine, but what I was wondering is if there's a way to mount/unmount my google drive with a key binding while I'm in the Gallium GUI without having to open a terminal.

I've opened the keyboard app and tried a few things with Application Shortcuts but nothing seems to work. Every command I've attached to my desired keybinding does nothing at all. Maybe I'm not using the correct command? Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.